# Improve the performance of Data retrieving in JSON format

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, performance

Now We are developing a Hybrid App and here data is accessing from Server side and given data is in JSON format. Its takes more than 10 seconds to load the data from server.

Here is its sample code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cardetails").tap(function(event,ui){   

      $.ajax({       
          url:'http://wwwsampleurl.net/json/jsn_cmp.php?json=1&rcg_mobile=2&lan=en&callback=ajax_eup&pick_up_loc=AGPT01&drop_off_loc=AGPT01&country_des=ES&country_user=AE&currency=EUR&day_drop=Tue&day_pick=Tue&age_driver=30&uid=0&num_days=7&pick_up=2722&drop_off=2722&pick_up_day=13&pick_up_hour=10&pick_up_minute=00&pick_up_mon=08&pick_up_year=2013&drop_off_day=20&drop_off_hour=10&drop_off_minute=00&drop_off_mon=08&drop_off_year=2013',
          data:'',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          crossDomain:true,
          cache: false,
          async:false,
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
              $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                  if(index=='gen'){
                      alert("gen data - "+val.pick_up_day);
                  }
                  else if(index=='company_date'){//alert('Load cars')
                      for (var i = 0, len = val.length; i < len; i++) {

                          //alert(JSON.stringify(val[i]));   
                          //    alert(val[i].car_img);
                          $('#carImages').append('<img src="'+val[i].car_img+'" width="70" height="110" alt="'+val[i].car_group+'" title="'+val[i].type+'"/>');
                       }
                   }

               });

           },
           error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(textStatus +"-"+ errorThrown);}

        });       
    });

});
```

How we can improve the performance?

Comment: You can try concating the string and appending it after the loop. And if it takes 10 seconds to load from server, you mean including the appending of the results or 10 seconds untill server returns the data?

Comment: Are you sure it's not an issue with the server response time / database query?

Comment: you need to see where the actual slowdown is. Is it in your query? In your return to page? How many rows are you returning? Above code doesn't tell us anything useful

Answer (score 0):

As previous said you should build up an internal variable and add it to the DOM after the loop.

Maybe you could optimize a bit on the server side, the if(index=='gen') is a bit costly. Hard to say wothout seeing the data that comes from the server.

Comment: Currently we have 16.4 KB size of data are coming (JSON format) from server. and for response and fetch data in pages it takes more than 16 seconds. But We aim to achieve all these in 3-6 seconds or maximum 8 seconds.

Comment: It takes 10 seconds to retrieve data from server. and for appending data it takes some more minutes. so total it takes more than 15 seconds.

Answer (score -2):

Never Use Jquery's  $.each , it will lead to performance issues in case the number of data iterated are more.
Use Native JS for

Comment: How can i use native for instead of this code ; $.each(data, function(index, val) {
       cl.append('<option value='+val.CODE+'>'+val.NAME+'</option>');
       });

Comment: `for` is [significantly faster](http://jsperf.com/each-vs-for-when-used-with-arrays) than `$.each()`, but on my computer `$.each()` can still process about *15,000,000 elements per second* (2700*5500). The OP says he has 16.4kb of data. Let's generously assume that it's an array with as many elements as possible (`["","",...]`). That's about the 5500 elements in the jsperf test. On my computer processing that array with `$.each()` takes about 0.36 milliseconds (0.00036 seconds). `for` takes 0.055 ms (0.000055 seconds). By switching from `$.each()` to `for` you would save about 0.0003 seconds.

Comment: ULLAS ,your 'data' is an array,so u can make use of for loop..      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){                                          var subData=data[i]; var code=subData.CODE;}   Though this is like touching nose around head,yet its faster when no of elements are more.

Comment: @SaiPrasadSabeson Did you even read my comment? The speed difference is *less than one millisecond*. It doesn't solve the problem of 10 second load time.